# Facebook Messenger - greeting text and get started button

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Was anybody able to make the [greeting text](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/greeting-text) on the Messenger platform work ?
The API is very simple and when I curl it (as described in the example in the link) it returns "Successfully updated greeting" but nothing really happens...

To clarify I'm simply using the example from the fb docs:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"greeting",
  "greeting":{
    "text":"Welcome to My Company!"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=XXXXX"
```

Where XXXXX is ofc replaced with my real token. As I mentioned the response seems to be good returning: "Successfully updated greeting".

Also, cant his co-exist with the [get started button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/get-started-button) ? In theory I don't see a reason why not and there is (ofc) nothing documented on this in developers.facebook.com, but like I said, while the get started button is easily configured, the greeting text simply doesn't work...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I think this part of the API is deprecated. Instead use this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "greeting":[
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "text":"Hello {{user_first_name}}!"
    }, {
      "locale":"en_US",
      "text":"Timeless apparel for the masses."
    }
  ] 
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=XXXXX"
```

Look that the path and body are differents like the response:

```
{
  "result":"success"
}
```

I hope I can help you :)

Source of doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/greeting-text

Answer (score 0):

maybe you hit the limitation of UTF-8 and 160 character?
It will be helpful if you could attach your code.

Comment: Don't think that's the issue as I'm almost completely copy-pasting fb own example (I've updated my initial Q to be more clear).

Answer (score 0):

Greeting text appears only once for a user when the user interacts with your chat bot for the very first time. If you have seen it already, you won't see it again. From the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/greeting-text):

> The Greeting Text is only rendered the first time the user interacts
>   with a the Page on Messenger.

You can add another test user in your app roles to see the greeting text again.

For your second question, 'Get Started' button triggers a [postback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/postback-received) with a user defined payload.

```
{
  "sender":{
    "id":"USER_ID"
  },
  "recipient":{
    "id":"PAGE_ID"
  },
  "timestamp":1458692752478,
  "postback":{
    "payload":"USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
  }
}
```

You can check in your webhook code if it receives this payload, then you can send your greeting message to the sender id. Also, you can set a similar text for this greeting message like the one you're using for your 'Greeting Text'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if this is even if u change the greeting text ? If so, I don't really understand how this can be tested other than creating endless amounts of fb test users...
Contrary to this, you can delete the conversation thread (on the web app) and then see and interact with the "Get started" button again and again. I just assumed I will see the same behavior with the greeting text.

Comment: 'Greeting Text' is just a generic template. You don't have to create a new test user every time you change your 'Greeting Text'. Just send that message to yourself using send api curl request to see the changes. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/generic-template

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. The 'Greeting Text' is something you set in the "page level" it's not something you can send to a specific user. So I don't see how what you suggested can be done. Can you show a specific code example ?

Comment: You're right .. My bad .. 'Greeting Text' itself is not a generic template and we cannot send it to users. It's just simple text and We can only set it using a curl request .. But still, It renders only once for a user. Do you really want to see it again? I mean, it's just a simple text .. :)

Comment: I agree it's not a very complicated API :)
Even so, I would expect a simple way to be able test yourself after you do changes on your page. Unfortunately it seems the only way to do this (without only relying on the fb API response text) is to create endless user test accounts...

Comment: Get started button appears but webhook payload not getting triggered on pressing it

Answer (score -1):

You can now set the Greeting Text from the Facebook Page. Click settings on the right, select Messenger from the list and scroll down to edit the Greeting Text.

I believe the Greeting Text is static on the Facebook Messenger Page. So if you can set this inside Facebook, that might be the easiest option.